# Derived classes from abstract template base class in c++

Tags: c++

I have a couple of abstract virtual class that all have a single pure virtual method. The difference of these base classes are the return type of the virtual method. For example,

```
class A{
protected:
virtual returnType1* Build()=0;
public:
returnType1 GetProduct();
}

class B{
protected:
virtual returnType2* Build()=0;
public:
returnType2 GetProduct();
}

class C{
protected:
virtual returnType3* Build()=0;
public:
returnType3 GetProduct();
}

class D:public A{
virtual returnType1 Build ()
{
....
}
}

class E:public B{
virtual returnType2 Build ()
{
....
}
}

class F:public C{
virtual returnType3 Build()
{
....
}
}
```

From these classes, I create a set of derived classes,and the clients use these derived classes. Do I really need three base class (or more than three)? Is it possible to write a single template base class? If it is possible, how it should be? and how to create a derived class from a template base class?

Comment: Like this? https://godbolt.org/z/h9fEPnjfx

Comment: Similar to [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) pattern, however in your case you just want to use the template parameter for the return type, not to use as an interface.

Comment: OT, but wouldn't you need to terminate your `class`es with a semicolon?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.Thank you joergbrech.